# How should I include a block of text that appears on multiple pages in my application?

Tags: angularjs

I have this block that appears on ten different admin pages:

```
<div class="displayTable w100p"
     id="modalTitle">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>{{home.modal.title}} {{home.modal.data.number}}</span>
            <span ng-show="home.modal.data.name"> - {{ home.modal.data.name | truncate:true:50:' ...' }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="alignRight fadein fadeout"
             id="modalMessage"
             ng-model="home.modal.message"
             ng-show="home.modal.message">
            {{home.modal.message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I heard about directives and also includes but I would like to know are these ways that I could include this text in my pages? If so then which would be the best. Note that the block above is identical in all my admin pages.

Comment: I would just use ng-include since it's just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.**

Save your html to separate file, f.e. *path/modal.html*.

**Step 2a.**

Directive:

```
app.directive('modal', function(){
  return: {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "path/modal.html"
  }
})
```

Use it.

```
<div modal></div>
```

**Step 2b.**

Ng-include:

```
<div ng-include="'path/modal.html'"></div>
```

**PS**
Check that your *home* variable defined in scope upper where you put your call.

Comment: I am sorry I am confused. I should use step 1 and 2a and 2b ? that does not make sense.

Comment: I mean Step 1 and 2a or 2b